# How to correctly abstract data access layer (for database, rest api calls, json) in C#?

Tags: c#, json, dependency-injection, cqrs, data-access-layer

I've been developing an application that uses various data connections (like database, rest api calls, json config files) in C#. I'm currently struggling to create a sensible data access layer abstraction that would enable to switch between these easily. Each of these require a different connection settings and also work differently.

I've looked at the example of the Repository pattern, but this doesn't really suit my needs. I want to be able to define some query pattern, which I can parametrize and that query will be able to handle the parameters. Example of what I currently have:

```
    public interface IQuery<TResult>
    {
    }

    public interface IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult>
        where TQuery : IQuery<TResult>
    {
        TResult Handle(TQuery query);
    }

    public class DatabaseQuery<TResult> : IQuery<IEnumerable<TResult>>
    {
        public string ConnectionString { get; set; }

        public string CommandText { get; set; }
    }

    public class DatabaseConnection<TQuery, TResult> : IQueryHandler<TQuery, IEnumerable<TResult>>
        where TQuery : DatabaseQuery<TResult>
    {
        public IEnumerable<TResult> Handle(TQuery query)
        {
            var results = new List<TResult>();

            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(query.ConnectionString))
            using (var command = new SqlCommand(query.CommandText, connection))
            {
                connection.Open();

                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        results.Add(...
                    }
                }
            }

            return results;
        }
    }

    public class JsonQuery<TResult> : IQuery<IEnumerable<TResult>>
    {
        public string FileLocation { get; set; }

        public Func<TResult, bool> Condition { get; set; }
    }

    public class JsonConnection<TQuery, TResult> : IQueryHandler<TQuery, IEnumerable<TResult>>
        where TQuery : JsonQuery<TResult>
    {
        public IEnumerable<TResult> Handle(TQuery query)
        {
            var text = File.ReadAllText(query.FileLocation);
            return Deserialize<TResult>(text).Results.Where(query.Condition);
        }
    }

    public interface IQueryBuilder<TQuery, TParameters>
    {
        TQuery Build(TParameters parameters);
    }

    public class GetAccountsByStatusAndBalanceHigherThanQueryParameters
    {
        public string Status { get; set; }

        public decimal Balance { get; set; }
    }        

    public class GetAccountsByStatusAndBalanceHigherThan_DatabaseQueryBuilder : 
        IQueryBuilder<DatabaseQuery<Account>, GetAccountsByStatusAndBalanceHigherThanQueryParameters>
    {
        public DatabaseQuery<Account> Build(GetAccountsByStatusAndBalanceHigherThanQueryParameters parameters)
        {
            return new DatabaseQuery<Account>()
            {
                ConnectionString = "connString",
                CommandText = $"SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE Status = {parameters.Status} AND Balance = {parameters.Balance}"
            };
        }
    }

    public class GetAccountsByStatusAndBalanceHigherThan_JsonQueryBuilder
        : IQueryBuilder<JsonQuery<Account>, GetAccountsByStatusAndBalanceHigherThanQueryParameters>
    {
        public JsonQuery<Account> Build(GetAccountsByStatusAndBalanceHigherThanQueryParameters parameters)
        {
            return new JsonQuery<Account>()
            {
                FileLocation = "fileLocation",
                Condition = acc => acc.Status == parameters.Status && acc.Balance > parameters.Balance
            };
        }
    }

    public class GetAccountsByStatusAndBalanceHigherThanQuery : IQuery<IEnumerable<Account>>
    {
        public string Status { get; set; }

        public decimal Balance { get; set; }
    }

    public class GetAccountsByStatusAndBalanceHigherThanQueryHandler :
        IQueryHandler<GetAccountsByStatusAndBalanceHigherThanQuery, IEnumerable<Account>>           
    {
        private readonly IQueryBuilder<JsonQuery<Account>, GetAccountsByStatusAndBalanceHigherThanQueryParameters> 
            _queryBuilder;

        private readonly IQueryHandler<JsonQuery<Account>, IEnumerable<Account>> _connection;

        public GetAccountsByStatusAndBalanceHigherThanQueryHandler(
            IQueryBuilder<JsonQuery<Account>, GetAccountsByStatusAndBalanceHigherThanQueryParameters> queryBuilder,
            IQueryHandler<JsonQuery<Account>, IEnumerable<Account>> connection)
        {
            _queryBuilder = queryBuilder;
            _connection = connection;
        }

        public IEnumerable<Account> Handle(GetAccountsByStatusAndBalanceHigherThanQuery query)
        {
            var jsonQuery = _queryBuilder.Build(new GetAccountsByStatusAndBalanceHigherThanQueryParameters
            { 
                Status = query.Status,
                Balance = query.Balance
            });

            return _connection.Handle(jsonQuery);
        }
    }
```

So there are two connections - one database and one Json file connection. I have put the settings to the connections into queries - and while database connection requires connection string and SQL command, the Json connection requires file location and some filtering on the results. The problem is in the last query handler - GetAccountsByStatusAndBalanceHigherThanQueryHandler. I need to make that depend on specific connection, otherwise I can't get it to compile. What I want is to make sure that I can change the connection by just changing the injected parameters and all will work correctly.

Could you please advise on how to make sure that I can change the connections easily and also whether this architecture is good at all?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be overcomplicating this. It looks to me like you have two data sources to retrieve the same data - one is a json data source and a database. This fits pretty neatly into the land of "one interface, multiple implementations". You'll also need a class to sort out which implementation you should use (this is a perfect use case for a factory). The complicated querying logic you're trying to pass into the constructors you could pass as method arguments.

Code would look something like this:

```
public interface IAccountDataAccess 
{
  IEnumerable<Account> GetAccountsHigherThanBalance(Status status, Balance balance);
  // etc.
}

public class JsonAccountDataAccess : IAccountDataAccess 
{

  private string jsonFilePath;
  public JsonAccountDataAccess(string _jsonFilePath)
  {
    jsonFilePath = _jsonFilePath;
  }

  public IEnumerable<Account> GetAccountsHigherThanBalance(Status status, Balance balance) 
  {
    // read json file, extract data, etc.
  }
}

public class DatabaseAccountDataAccess : IAccountDataAccess 
{

  private string connectionString;
  public DatabaseAccountDataAccess(string _connectionString)
  {
    connectionString = _connectionString;
  }

  public IEnumerable<Account> GetAccountsHigherThanBalance(Status status, Balance balance) 
  {
    // read database, extract data, etc.
  }
}
```

Here's the tricky part - you need a factory to spit out the correct implementation given some input. I'm not sure how you're planning to decide whether to use JSON or the database, but assuming that your client class knows:

```
public class AccountDataAccessFactory 
{
  public IAccountDataAccess GetDataAccess(bool useDatabase) 
  {
    if(useDatabase) // you could use arbitrarily complex logic here
      return new DatabaseAccountDataAccess(connString);
    else 
      return new JsonAccountDataAccess(jsonFilePath);
  }
}
```

Your client class could use it like this:

```
var factory = new AccountDataAccessFactory();
var dataAccess = factory.GetDataAccess(true);
var accounts = dataAccess.GetAccountsHigherThanBalance(status, balance);
```

Comment: Although your proposed solution would certainly make this case easier, the problem is that I have multiple various queries to be made. If I put them all in the IAccountDataAccess interface, I'd have violated single responsibility principle. In fact, not all queries are meant to be done with both connections.

Also another problem I have - and that's what really is the core of my question, I'd have to reimplement database access for DatabaseAccountDataAccess, again for DatabaseCustomerDataAccess etc. That is what I would like to get rid of - the necessity for rewriting the data connections.

Comment: Do you mean that you have to choose the data source based on the query?

Comment: Not in the example I provided, but yes, that occurs also. There are about 20 databases (that look pretty much the same) I have to connect to - based on what the user inputs.